# HTML/CSS: unknown region

Tags: html, css

On [this page](http://secretcitywalks.co/wp/london/), there is a gap just above the footer navigation menu:

[image]

Chrome code inspector says this region is `div#primary`, yet why does it extend across this empty space down to the top of the bottom navigation menu?

There are no HTML elements here.

`div#content` is represented above by the blue rectangle.

What is filling the region indicated by the red arrows above?

Comment: If you add the CSS of this elements, we can help you better.

Comment: Likely a margin on something. Please put the code into a fiddle or something.

Comment: `<article>` has a lot of `margin-bottom`, `padding-bottom` and `border` stuff. It comes from there, even though the Developer Tools feature does not make it obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `margin-bottom: 5.142857143rem;` on the `.site-content article`. If you change that to `margin-bottom: 0;` for example the white space is pretty much gone.

Answer (score 3):

.site-content article have margin-bottom: 5.142857143rem;. This margin make the white space below the content

Answer (score 2):

set 0 bottom padding .site-content article

or you can code inline css (margin-bottom: 0px;) in ( article id="post-178" )

Answer (score 2):

The `<article>` tag has a `margin-bottom: 5.142857143rem;`.

[image: Element inspector screenshot]